# CSS not loading inside sub directory

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to load the css from a sub directory through index.php and have defined a constant `AMIN_CSS ="http://localhost/gbl_admin/admin_css"`.

This being in the same directory loads the css:

```
<link href="<?php echo ADMIN_PAGE."/style.css"?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but this one is in the sub directory:

```
<link href="<?php echo ADMIN_PAGE."/admin_css/style.css"?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">


 //constant decleration
 define("SITEURL",'http://'.@$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/");  
 define("ADMIN_PAGE",SITEURL."gbl_admin");
 define("ADMIN_SCRIPTS",SITEURL."gbl_admin/admin_scripts");
 define("ADMIN_CSS",SITEURL."gbl_admin/admin_css");
```

This one doesn't load!! How can i solve this?

Comment: Have you checked the path when the file is loaded? (You can check the path with your browsers dev tools by pressing F12).

Comment: Can you show your directory structure for index and style.css files

Comment: inside gbl_admin: index.php dir(admin_css) style.css
inside admin_css:style.css

Comment: Can you please post how did you defined your constant

Comment: Check permission as well

Comment: Try this --> <link href="<?php echo ADMIN_PAGE.'/style.css'?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: define("SITEURL",'http://'.@$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/");
define("ADMIN_PAGE",SITEURL."gbl_admin");
define("ADMIN_SCRIPTS",SITEURL."gbl_admin/admin_scripts");
define("ADMIN_CSS",SITEURL."gbl_admin/admin_css");

Comment: did you tryed the above code

Comment: yeah that loads since the index.php is in the same directory i need to get the file from admin_css directory
 
These both don't work
<link href="<?php echo ADMIN_CSS.'/style.css'?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php echo ADMIN_PAGE.'/admin_css/style.css'?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Can you show us the html source? Can you open links directly from html source? What is the result?

Comment: directly opening http://localhost/gbl_admin/admin_css/style.css works not through reference though 
<link href="<?php  if(isset($root)){echo $root.'/admin_css/style.css';}?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
$root=realpath(\_\_DIR\_\_);

Comment: try to use the url as `/gbl_admin/admin_css` instead of `http://localhost/gbl_admin/admin_css`.

Answer (score 1):

The second link which you are referring is perceived as

http://localhost/gbl_admin/admin_css/admin_css/style.css

You can see that admin_css is repeated twice hence it is not able to load the CSS File. Hence the correct url should be as follows :

http://localhost/gbl_admin/admin_css/style.css

Comment: sorry buti edited the question i was trying using ADMIN_CSS AND ADMIN_PAGE constant and in browser ispect panel the href=http://localhost/gbl_admin/admin_css/style.css

Comment: there is no repeatation of diectory at all