# Acessing files in sub directory:

Tags: php, file

i asked a question regarding not being able to load css file from sub directory while scripting through php.

[CSS not loading inside sub directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318507/css-not-loading-inside-sub-directory)

I didn't get a answer which could solve my problem. 
Today while trying to include a image from subdirectory again it couldn't be accessed.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <title>********</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="<?php echo ADMIN_CSS.'/style.css'?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <?php get_header() ?>

            <div class="main_body">
            </div>  


            <?php get_footer() ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html
```

get_header():

```
............
<div class="image_left">
                        <img src="<?php echo ADMIN_FILES."/logo.png" ?>" width="76px" height="76px"/>  
                    </div>
.......
```

Constant Defining:

```
define("SITEURL",'http://'.@$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/");
define("ADMIN_PAGE",SITEURL."gbl_admin");
define("ADMIN_SCRIPTS",SITEURL."gbl_admin/admin_scripts");
define("ADMIN_CSS",SITEURL."gbl_admin/admin_css");
define("ADMIN_FILES",ADMIN_PAGE."/admin_files");
```

Here's my file System of gbl_admin:

```
05/19/2015  07:04 PM    <DIR>          .
05/19/2015  07:04 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/18/2015  11:32 AM             4,276 admin_add.php
05/17/2015  01:31 PM               373 admin_control.php
05/19/2015  05:35 PM    <DIR>          admin_css
05/19/2015  01:21 PM    <DIR>          admin_files
05/19/2015  02:32 PM             1,836 admin_layout.php
05/06/2015  04:12 PM    <DIR>          admin_scripts
05/17/2015  01:33 PM    <DIR>          configuration
05/19/2015  01:26 PM    <DIR>          db
05/19/2015  07:04 PM               825 index.php
05/17/2015  01:33 PM             3,123 login.php
05/19/2015  07:04 PM             3,445 style.css
               6 File(s)         13,878 bytes
               7 Dir(s)   7,932,063,744 bytes free
```

I also tried using realpath(__DIR__) through index.php file but all my attempts ending in a failure. I can add php files through require() even though it is in sub directory but i can't load the style files and images files from the sub directory. If it is due permission how do i solve it? If not what can i do do to make this code work?(BTW I Can access the files if they are in same directory as of index.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS not loading inside sub directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318507/css-not-loading-inside-sub-directory)

Comment: are you reading the question at all? I am being serious man i though i could get help here. It's a duplicate but i have tried so much thing since yesterday that i can't find the answer by myself

Comment: check the HTML that is generated. look at the path to the image file. Is that path correct? i.e.: can you access the image file by copy-pasting the generated url?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/779nvg yeah they are correct

Comment: So, if you copy-paste the link that is generated, the image is displayed, but it is not displayed in your web page?

Comment: sry this one from ADMIN_CSS link http://prntscr.com/779o6s

Comment: yeah http://prntscr.com/779olu

Comment: That is unusual... Have you tried in a different browser? Have you ruled out that something is hiding the (otherwise correct) image?

Comment: yeah my only choice now is to use another compilation of apache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78292/discussion-between-burki-and-hengecyche).

Comment: If you don't get an acceptable answer with a question, try editing it to be clearer/more precise instead of posting a totally equivalent brand new question. With a single well-expressed question, your contribution will be way more valuable for the community.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
define("ADMIN_CSS",SITEURL."gbl_admin/admin_css");
```

to

```
define("ADMIN_CSS",SITEURL."gbl_admin");
```

because your css is not in gbl_admin/admin_css its in gbl_admin

Comment: there is a style file inside admin_css. the file outside is the one i am currently using for the time being but i want to be able to access the files from the sub directory

Comment: and the image from admin_files won't even appear

Answer (score 0):

When accessing the a script in one sub directory level above use the `../` operator in php